# How get font names in CKEditor 4? config.font_names is undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to add my own fonts to CKEditor 4. But I also want to keep the installed default fonts. The code I've found online is:

```
config.font_names = "MyNewFont," + config.font_names;
```

But this results in just showing MyNewFont and removing all the other fonts. I've checked via `console.dir( config )` and `console.log( config.font_names );` and discovered that `font_names` is `undefined`. But the default fonts all show up if I remove my line, so it's getting it from somewhere.

What's the proper way to add my font in CKEditor 4?

**EDIT** It appears that the `font_names` property is being set very late in the process, during plugin loading. If I set it before that, then it uses only the one font I added. If I set it after (i.e. `editor.on( "pluginsLoaded",...);` ) then it's too late. The only solution I was able to find was to edit the font plugin's `plugin.js` file to add my font into their list.